# How to analyze requests (with queries) on swagger and send different response body?

Tags: rest, api, swagger, swagger-2.0, apprequests

Is that possible to analyze the request (based on queries) on swagger hub api 3.0?

For example, I need to reproduce the next thing.

For request `getUser?id=1` swager swagger has to send response to client

```
{
  "user_id": "1"
  "user_name": "Alex",
}
```

For request `getUser?id=2` swager swagger has to send response to client

```
{
  "user_id": "2"
  "user_name": "Bob",
}
```

If that possible, could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is about [SwaggerHub mock server](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/integrations/api-auto-mocking). According to the documentation, this is not supported:

> Note that the mock does not support business logic, that is, it cannot send specific responses based on the input.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.